# Compute $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt x(1-x)^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried substituting $x=e^{2t}$ and rearranging the expression, but could not proceed any further. Apparently it breaks down into the difference of two separate integrals, both of which I don't believe can be computed by standard integration methods.

Comment: Please see [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Check out the answer at [Integral ${\frac{1}{\pi^2}} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{(\ln{x}})^2}{\sqrt{x}{(1-x)^2}} \mathrm d x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137203/integral-frac1-pi2-int-0-infty-frac-lnx2-sqrtx1-x)